# Woocommerce product fee plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a plugin and I can't figure it out on how to fix it.

**The product fee is always displayed in the cart even if i don't enter any data.**
[image]
This is the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-fees/) before updating.

**The issue appeared after I downloaded the latest version from** [github](https://github.com/WPprodigy/woocommerce-product-fees)

I went over the files , compared them but I just can't figure it out where the problem is.I dont see any php errors.
I also disabled other plugins,and everything is up to date.
Thank you.

Comment: Would you please tell me the version of WooCommerce Product Fees which is you use?

Comment: @Dhruvin Moradiya the woocommerce version is 3.2.3 and this product fee plugin version is Version 1.3.0-beta , its the one from github . thank you

Comment: seems working fine for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaKSK.png

Comment: @vel its working fine but , if i add a product with no fee set in input , it shows 0 which is not ok. i dont want to show the fee if i have no fee understand ? thank you

If you set fee to a product , and add it to cart , and then add another one with no fee , you will see it shows both fees ( the one you set and the 0 fee)

Comment: Would you please install plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-fees/ ? It is completely working as per your need in my site.

Comment: @Dhruvin Moradiya , yes that one is working but some functions are deprecated in it.

Another question , Would you happend to know why this product fee is not showing inside a CSV file when i try to export orders ? see here https://ibb.co/f0Lgsb , the order is Completed.I tested more export orders plugins but none is exporting this product fee

Comment: For export orders into CSV file have you use any plugin?

Comment: @DhruvinMoradiya  Yes i tested with few export orders plugins , for example https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-order-export-lite/ . It exports the order but not the product fee for some reason

Comment: You need to customize wordpress.org/plugins/woo-order-export-lite for display product fee separately.

Comment: @DhruvinMoradiya i dont know how :( , any tips where to start ? ty